# What is the difference between Weapon Accuracy and Critical Hit Accuracy?

Tags: overwatch

When viewing statistics for various heroes under Career Profile, most heroes have a Weapon Accuracy and a Critical Hit Accuracy stat.

I assume that "critical hit" refers to headshots, and "weapon accuracy" is how accurate you are with a weapon, of course.

What I don't understand is what "critical hit accuracy" is. How is this different from "weapon accuracy"?

Answer (score 4):

**Weapon Accuracy:** Out of all of the shots you fired, how many you hit. For example: out of 100 Shots fired, 50 shots hit, so you have 50% Weapon Accuracy.

**Critical Hit Accuracy:** Out of all the shots you hit, how many were critical (headshots). For example, out of 200 shots fired, 100 shots hit, but 20 were criticals, so you have 20% Critical Hit Accuracy.

And going a step further, Widowmaker has a special stat called **Scoped Critical Accuracy**, which is the accuracy for criticals dealt while scoped (so the SMG shots don't count)

Comment: Tangentially related question: Do the shots fired during the "setup phase" (when everyone is in the lobby waiting for the match to begin) count towards your weapon accuracy?

Comment: This is what I would assume from the stat names. Did you do anything more than assume?

Answer (score 2):

It's the percentage of how much of your shots are critical hits. Basically, if you have 10 shots in your record and 2 of them are headshots for example, your critical hit accuracy would be 20%.

I do not know whether or not missed shots are counted in this stat, however.

Comment: I would assume it's a percentage of hits that are crits, not a percentage of shots that are crits, but would need to test.